# Problem of 3D object rotation using manipulators

Tags: interface

Some time ago I began to study Blender. I did not have problems. Recently, after the break, I downloaded version 2.79 and I immediately had a problem. I can not rotate a 3D object using the manipulator. Regardless of the choice of the arc, the blender rotates the object around the vertical axis Z. Attempts to mark another axis in the group of check boxes "Constraint Axis" do not help. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could u provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I submitted a screenshot as an additional question, posted below.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has the same problem: Careful with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>  (comma) this shortcut enables Manipulate center points. With that enabled, rotation and scaling will not have any visible effect on the objects.

Comment: Thank you for your desire to help. Unfortunately, I did not understand your answer. Alt use when moving the mouse with the left button pressed rotates the entire scene, not the selected object.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is an attempt to rotate the cube that appears in the 2.79 window using the rotation manipulator. Regardless of the selected arc, the cube rotates only around the vertical axis Z

Comment: You can edit your questions on SE... you don't need to make this appear as an 'answer'

Comment: They do not show up here, but maybe the axis are locked ?  You can check this by pressing N.

Comment: That's just the point, that no axis is marked as locked! It seems that the Z axis is locked by default and I can not undo it. Maybe this is a bug version 2.79? Or maybe you can cancel it in User Preference?

Comment: Got no problems here on 2.79... There should be something locking it... But what :)  No constraints set ?  Maybe you should share your file.

Comment: Thank you for your desire to help. I just open the Blender 2.79 and try to rotate the default cube by using the manipulator around the X or Y axis, and instead the Blender rotates it around the Z axis. Unfortunately, I do not know how to share this file through a comment.